# ECharts: Use equation instead of data for 2D graphs

Tags: javascript, echarts

In the 3D surface plot example below the series data source is omitted and an equation property is provided. I'm looking to do the same for other plot types, for example a simple 2D 'line' plot.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=simple-surface&gl=1

```js
  series: [
    {
      equation: {
        x: { step: 0.05 },
        y: { step: 0.05 },
        z: function (x, y) { return x * y; }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Above is the (simplified) relevant option section in the 3D surface plot example. Doing the same for a 2D 'line' plot doesn't seem to work, it looks like the equation property is ignored. Can this work or should I pre-compute data?

I'd rather use the equation style as the plot will output equation values anyway and I'd like to use dataZoom without interpolating data.